# Session based authentication in api-platform

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I am trying to setup session based authentication instead of JWT that I have currently in use, because I don´t want to store JWT token in local storage.

I have managed to authenticate myself using this guide https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/json_login_setup.html and get response data about the user.

But further requests to any endpoint I get 401 unauthorized.

This is my security yaml

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
providers:
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/_(profiler|wdt)
        security: false
    api:
        pattern: ^/api/
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login
            username_path: email
            password_path: password
            #success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            #failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        #guard:
        #   authenticators:
        #      - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
    main:
        anonymous: true
access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/authentication_token,   roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/graphql,                roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/form/,                  roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/,                       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/,                           roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

On the official api-platform documentation there is no word of using session based login which I find odd.

Thank you

Comment: The first question is why do you want to use sessions in API? Basically APIs are supposed to be stateless - every request is not related to another and authenticated separately. API-Platform is designed for building REST APIs thus it follows the rule.

Comment: So instead of keeping a token you came up with an idea to keep a session id instead? ;) Sounds familiar?

Comment: @emix According to the internet sessions are somehow more durable to xss attacks, and storing jwt in local storage is not recommended. It´s safe until I don´t use third party script, but as soon there is third party script from remote source it becomes vulnerable. I am new to this topic, but from my research storing jwt in browser is considered as bad practice, if it would be some mobile/desktop/backend(java/php/..) app that requests data from the API with some secure storage it would be safe to use jwt.

Comment: Nobody's forcing you to keep JWT in the local storage. You might as well keep it in a cookie. There's no relation between a session (storage mechanism) and a xss (an attack vector). If you accept 3rd party malicious content you are still f*** anyway.

Comment: @Vokiel Just wanted to answer to your answer you removed, so what are you suggesting then? Because sending authentication request / refresh token before each request to retrieve fresh token and then requesting new data feels as waste of resources, basically doubling the requests.

Comment: @emix I guess you are right about the third party (which i don´t plan to use). Maybe I should implement some token refreshing mechanism on each request / time based every X minutes to invalidate stolen tokens, just in case. do you have any better idea?

Comment: JWT tokens should be refreshed once in a while. See [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119371/is-refreshing-an-expired-jwt-token-a-good-strategy). Who steals tokens anyway? ;) it's all about phising these days.

Comment: @ErikKubica you authorize user once, generate JWT, then user uses it multiple times without re-generating after every request. If you have a frontend application, then you can create JWT on login and invalidate it on logout.
Also, to make it more secure and attack-proof you can embed user IP into the token so even in case of MITM attack it would be useless. Of course, having SSL/TLS is a must ;-)

Comment: Thanks emix and Vokiel for the tips i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `stateless: true` or change it to `stateless: false`

> The `stateless` configuration parameter prevents Symfony from trying to
>   store the authentication information in the session

All else looks good to me, however if this does not solve your issue can you add any message that is returned with the `401` response code to you queston?

Comment: Thanks mate. in the end i will probably keep using jwt, but your answer might be useful for others or in different project.

Comment: This entry is old, but I'm in the same situation. Anybody know how can It solve?

I changed stateless: false, but all the requests to any endpoint continue getting 401 unauthorized.

Thanks!

Comment: @Raúl looks like my next project will be on api-platform and statefull auth, did you figure it out in the end? if yes how? and can you share your experience with it?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. If you received an authorization token, just make one request to the server with this token. And then your Symfony session will start working as well. After that, you no longer need to add the token to the http headers. And yes, of course this parameter should look like

> stateless: false

As mentioned above